# How do I get rid of the spaces between the characters in the output using a print(), statement in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code that I have.

```
secretMessageList = [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33]
for c in secretMessageList:
    print chr(c),
```

And then the output looks like this.

```
D o n t   d e c o d e   t h i s   m e s s a g e   o r   e l s e !
```

Is there any way to make the output instead look like this?

```
Dont decode this message or else!
```

I tried looking up if there's any way to do this but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing each character, you could first make a string of all the elements and then print the result.

```
print(''.join(map(chr, [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33])))
```

`map(chr, values)` has a result that is "almost the same" as `[chr(c) for c in values]`. The returned value from `map()` (map object) then can be passed to functions like `list()` (to create a list), `set()` (to create a set) or use it directly in `join`.

A better readable solution would be

```
ints = [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33]
characters = [chr(c) for c in ints]
string = ''.join(characters)
print(string)
```

In python 2.x, the `print` method should be written without brackets, so you may need to remove those (because you tagged your question with `python-2.7`). For Python 3 and up, `print` does require brackets.

Happy coding, good luck!

Comment: chr() function returns the string and .join() method joins them.why str and map functions are used here? `print(''.join([chr(c) for c in [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33]]))` works just as well..

Comment: Good point. If `chr` is called, then `str` is not needed anymore. I've updated my answer. About `map`: `map(chr, values)` has a result that is almost the same as `[chr(c) for c in values]`. The returned value from map() (map object) then can be passed to functions like `list()` (to create a list), `set()` (to create a set)  or used in `join`.

Answer (score 1):

chr every item in your list then join them into string:

```
secretMessageList = [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33]
a="".join(list(chr(i) for i in secretMessageList))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is just to change the character `print` ends with:

```
secretMessageList = [68, 111, 110, 116, 32, 100, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 101, 108, 115, 101, 33]
for c in secretMessageList:
    print(chr(c), end='') #<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
print(''.join([chr(c) for c in secretMessageList]))
```